# Obtaining webcam images in rawest possible form?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, camera

My laptop is running Ubuntu. All of the applications that I have seen to capture from the webcam produce images that have been passed through brightness, hue and contrast adjustments. Is it possible to get the absolutely raw data from the webcam, that has not been processed at all? DSLRs produce raw files, I am looking to get something similar.